# Icons only showing in iOS Safari after browsing around a bit

Tags: ios, svg, safari, mobile-safari, font-awesome

I've embedded some font-awesome icons (with an svg filter below them) in this Meteor app: http://sm-starfire.meteor.com/. The rendering of the icons, however, is inconsistent in iOS Safari (on Mac Safari 8, the problem is limited to the first 2 posts).

Clicking on the menu button under each post will unfold the icons:

[image: Menu Button]

Upon first arrival on the home page, and clicking the menu buttons, the icons don't show

[image: No icons showing]

After clicking through to a single post though, the icons show up. And when returning to the home page, the icons are still visible.

[image]